# Animating Histograms with plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm trying to create an animated demonstration of the Law of Large Numbers, where I want to show the histogram converging to the density as the sample size increase.

I can do this with R shiny, putting a slider on the sample size, but when I try to set up a plotly animation using the sample size as the frame, I get an error deep in the bowels of ggploty.  Here is the sample code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
XXX <- rnorm(200)
plotdat <- bind_rows(lapply(25:200, function(i)   data.frame(x=XXX[1:i],f=i)))
hplot <- ggplot(plotdat,aes(x,frame=f)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.25)
ggplotly(hplot)
```

The last line returns the error. `Error in -data$group : invalid argument to unary operator`.

I'm not sure where it is suppose to be getting data$group (this value has been magically set for me in other invocations of ggplotly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skipping the initial ggplot and going straight to plotly, does this work for you?

```
plotdat %>%
  plot_ly(x=~x,
          type = 'histogram',
          frame = ~f) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(range = c(0,50)))
```

Or, using your original syntax, we can add a position specification that seems to prevent the bug. This version looks better, with standard ggplot formatting and tweened animation.

```
hplot <- ggplot(plotdat, aes(x, frame = f)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=.25, position = "identity")
ggplotly(hplot) %>%
  animation_opts(frame = 100) # minimum ms per frame to control speed
```

(I don't know why this fixes it, but when I googled your error I saw a plotly issue on github that was solved by specifying the position, and it seems to fix the error here too.  https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1544)